# Authentication failed when querying data from linked server with SQL authentication

Tags: sql, sql-server, linked-server

I have 2 SQL Servers on one machine. Lets call it Server1 and Server2. I need to access Server1 from Server2 through the linked server. And I have managed to configure it but querying the linked server works only when I am logged with windows authentication method to Server2. When I will log with SQL login 'sa' into Server2, I am getting an error when executing a query:

> The OLE DB provider "..." for linked server ".." reported an error.
> Authentication failed.

This is the security setting I am using in linked server configuration:

[Linked server security tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ENeHD.png)

Please help.

Error Log from the remote server:

```
06/24/2022 09:23:33,Logon,Unknown,Login failed for user 'NT Service\MSSQL$SQLEXPRESS'. Reason: Could not find a login matching the name provided. [CLIENT: <local machine>]
06/24/2022 09:23:33,Logon,Unknown,Error: 18456<c/> Severity: 14<c/> State: 5.
```

Comment: The login and password must be of the **remote** server.

Comment: SQL login and password in security tab of the linked server is correct for the remote server.

Comment: Please show the error log from the *remote* server, with an error code 18456

Comment: I have added error log to question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error Log from remote SQL server made me think, so I have added new user *NT Service\MSSQL$SQLEXPRESS* to remote server. Now I am available to run queries against linked server.

I am puzzled though why linked server is using network service account despite having configured remote sql login *sa* in security tab. I would appreciate if someone could clarify this to me.